# Adding Decimal to calculator

Tags: javascript, decimal, addition, calculator

I made a calculator using javascript , it works fine but it has some problems.

1. When I want to calculate the radical of number , when I click the radical button , it does not work but when I double click it , it works !
2. I do not know how to add decimal to my calculator , please help me

This is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var valid=false ,operand='', numCounter=1, firstNum=null, secondNum=null;
        function remov(){
            document.getElementById('result').value = null;
            secondNum = firstNum = null;
            numCounter=1;
        }
        function show(id){
            var val = document.getElementById(id).value;
            if(id=='+' || id=='-' || id=='*' || id=='/' || id=='^' || id=='√')
            {
                valid=true;
                if(numCounter > 1){
                    calc();
                }
                firstNum=Number(document.getElementById('result').value);
                numCounter++;
                operand=id;
            }
            else if(id == 'equal')
            {
                calc();
                numCounter=1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(valid){
                document.getElementById('result').value = null;
                valid=false;
                }
                document.getElementById('result').value += val;
            }
        }
        function calc(){
            if(numCounter > 1){
                secondNum=Number(document.getElementById('result').value);
            }else{
                firstNum=Number(document.getElementById('result').value);
            }
            switch(operand)
            {
                case '+':
                document.getElementById('result').value = firstNum+secondNum;
                break;
                case '-':
                document.getElementById('result').value = firstNum-secondNum;
                break;
                case '/':
                if(firstNum != 0)
                document.getElementById('result').value = firstNum/secondNum;
                else
                    document.getElementById('result').value = "Error";
                break;
                case '*':
                document.getElementById('result').value = firstNum*secondNum;
                break;
                case '^':
                document.getElementById('result').value = Math.pow(firstNum,secondNum);
                break;
                case '√':
                document.getElementById('result').value = Math.sqrt(firstNum);
                break;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

this is the HTML

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
    <div id="cal">
        <input id="result" type="text" readonly /><br/>
        <button value="1" id="1" onclick="show(1)">1</button>
        <button value="2" id="2" onclick="show(2)">2</button>
        <button value="3" id="3" onclick="show(3)">3</button>
        <button value="+" id="+" onclick="show('+')">+</button><br/>
        <button value="4" id="4" onclick="show(4)">4</button>
        <button value="5" id="5" onclick="show(5)">5</button>
        <button value="6" id="6" onclick="show(6)">6</button>
        <button value="-" id="-" onclick="show('-')">-</button><br/>
        <button value="7" id="7" onclick="show(7)">7</button>
        <button value="8" id="8" onclick="show(8)">8</button>
        <button value="9" id="9" onclick="show(9)">9</button>
        <button value="*" id="*" onclick="show('*')">*</button><br/>
        <button value="." id="." onclick="show('.')">.</button>
        <button value="0" id="0" onclick="show(0)">0</button>
        <button value="√" id="√" onclick="show('√')">√</button>
        <button value="/" id="/" onclick="show('/')">/</button><br/>
        <button onclick="remov()">C</button>
        <button value="^" id="^" onclick="show('^')">^</button>
        <button id="equal" value="=" onclick="show('equal')">=</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Although technically allowed (in HTML5), you shouldn't use numbers or symbols as the element IDs

Answer (score 1):

For decimals you can use `toFixed` - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

As per for the other problem, don't know.  Is it working for the other buttons when you only click once?